# Blocking ip range in hosts file?

Tags: macos, networking

I know how to edit my hosts file on osx, how can I block the range 78.31.8.0/22? What do I put in the hosts file?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot.

`/etc/hosts` is not for *blocking* – it is for translating domain names to addresses (when other methods are unavailable) – more specifically, an *exact name* to a *single* address. If a program tries to access the address directly, the system won't even touch `/etc/hosts`, because there will be nothing to look up.

Use a proper firewall, such as `ipfw`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to null a range of ip is:

`route add 78.31.8.0/22 lo`

Use the routing table to do it :)

Comment: how can I access the routing table?

Comment: You can just try the command I posted if you are using GNU/Linux :)